# What did '?' do in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I used to consider `?` as a symbol of `optional`, but the code below made me confused.

```js
type A = {
  name: string;
  foo?: {
    bar: string;
  };
};

const a: A = {
  name: "dd",
};

console.log(a.foo?.bar);
```

It printed `undefined`.

But if I remove the `?` it will report an error(which I think is understandable):

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bar')

Seems like `a.foo?` returned a empty object, why?

Comment: I know nothing about typescript, but my guess is that you created the type `A` which has a `foo` property that can be inexisting or may have an object with a property `bar` that takes a string. Since you didn't assign anything to the property `foo`, when declaring the constant `a`, the property `foo` doesn't exist or has no value (due to the ?).

Comment: I've decided to vote to re-open this question, as the question provided in the close reason doesn't explain why the observed behaviour is happening. It simply aswers a question about if a desired feature exists or not in the language. It doesn't explain how/why that feature behaves in the observed manner